# How can i get state name from city name with google map api?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've crated one autosuggest textbox using google auto suggest. I am having city name entered by user.

I want to add its state name at the end of city automatically. i am using google maps auto suggest and google maps javascript API v3.

http://geo-autocomplete.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demo/ui.demo.html

Please suggest ASAP.

Comment: possible duplicate [Google Maps: how to get country, state/province/region, city given a lat/long value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013606/google-maps-how-to-get-country-state-province-region-city-given-a-lat-long-va)

Comment: I've crated one autosuggest textbox using google auto suggest.
http://geo-autocomplete.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demo/ui.demo.html

Now if user enters only City name and not State, I automatically want to add State name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be something like this:

```
placemark.AddressDetails.Country.AdministrativeArea.AdministrativeAreaName
```