# get the city names the google map route going through

Tags: javascript

I am developing a web page using Google map API v3. Is there a way to collect the place or city names the route is going through to get from point A to B? I am using javascript in the page.

Answer (score 8):

Check out the [Directions API docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsResult). It looks like you are provided with a `DirectionsResult` object that contains an array of `DirectionsRoute`s. Each `DirectionsRoute` contains an array of `DirectionsLeg`s, which in turn is broken down even further into a set of `DirectionsStep`s. From each step you can pull the `start_location` and/or `end_location`, each of which is represented as Lat/Lng. From there, I'll let this answer take over on how to convert the Lat/Lng to a city (reverse-geocoding):

[Google Maps: how to get country, state/province/region, city given a lat/long value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013606/google-maps-how-to-get-country-state-province-region-city-given-a-lat-long-va)

In short, the directions Google Maps provided are broken down into many sub sections, and at most levels of granularity you can pull out the latitude/longitude and let Google's geocoding API handle converting that to a city name.