# google map help needed

Tags: html, google-maps

I have list where iam showing cities when a country is selected from a dropdown.Now accross each city iam showing google map icon.when the icon is clicked iam showing the google map of that city in an iframe in  facebox.The code for the iframe is;

```
<iframe width='425' height='350' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' marginheight='0' marginwidth='0' src='https://maps.google.com/maps?q=***$cityName***&hl=en&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;ll=37.0625,-95.677068&amp;spn=42.224734,56.513672&amp;t=m&amp;z=4&amp;output=embed'></iframe>
```

But its not showing that particular city in google map.Please have a look to it and suggest what should i do to get that perticular city.I have country name as well.

Thanxx in advance;

Comment: There is nothing to take a look at. Please share the code. not just the iframe tag.

Comment: thank you sir for your reply.Sir iam passing dynamically city name in the map src.kindly give me any solution where i can pass the city name and country name and get the map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `ll`-parameter from the URL.

When the `ll`-parameter is provided the map is centered at the position specified via the `ll`-parameter, not at the adress(when sucessfully geocoded) specified via the `q`-parameter.

http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/nvdCt/

Comment: thanks sir it worked.but iam ubable to get correct city in loop

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [reverse geocoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_geocoding) which help you get your particular country, city automatically when map is loaded.

You can find the reverse geocoding list [here](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=false)

You can read about [Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?hl=iw&csw=1#ReverseGeocoding) to help you understand more.

Also [related content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013606/google-maps-how-to-get-country-state-province-region-city-given-a-lat-long-va).