# Google Map capture the country once users clicked any point of that country

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am a newbie of programming Android with Google map API. I met a question about the capturing the target country, when the users click any point of the target country (e.g. US as below figure showed), how can I get the value "United States" on this onClick action??

Thanks for any comments or suggestion of my dumb question.

[image]

Comment: See this question on using Google's reverse geocoding API: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013606/google-maps-how-to-get-country-state-province-region-city-given-a-lat-long-va

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when user click onmap there is a listener called onMapClickListener()

```
googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng position) {
           //Get the lat long here from variable position
           //Use GeoCoder class to fetch the country from latlong like this
           Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getActivity(), Locale.getDefault()); 
           List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);         
           if(addresses.size() > 0){
               String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
           }
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Do I need to import any statement at the Import part for using GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener? Thanks.