# Is there any way to get Country of Sea in google map when clicked on map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I just need when I clicked on map then get latlang and also get country with that.
Need for Land and Natural features (like Sea).

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {               
                    var lat = event.latLng.lat();
                    var lang = event.latLng.lng();
                    var country =?
    });
```

Is there any features in google map ?

LatLang is = 57.326521225217064, 3.33984375

Comment: *"Is there any way to get Country of Sea..."* Heh, [according to whom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Territorial_disputes_in_the_South_China_Sea)?

Comment: You can take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013606/google-maps-how-to-get-country-state-province-region-city-given-a-lat-long-va

Comment: @Goran- Not working that    (may latlang is =57.326521225217064,3.33984375)

Comment: Your latLng is in [the middle of the North Sea](https://www.google.com/maps/place/57%C2%B019'35.5%22N+3%C2%B020'23.4%22E/@57.3265212,-1.1403892,6z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d57.3265212!4d3.3398438), why do you think that would be claimed by a country?

Comment: I just need make polygon there, When I'll clicked on google map then need to make polygon according to latlang with country.