# reverse geocoding without map

Tags: javascript, html

Using the below code to find local area from longitude and latitude, i'm not really wanting a specific address, just city or state.

The problem is that all I need is the city placed in to a variable, I dont want the map. Is this possible

I have taken this code from google developers site and put an alert box to display the address, which is fine, but dont want the map.

I have come across this which returns details from long/lat,

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?
   latlng=55.056499,1.600130&key=XXX&sensor=false

But getting this message - although not exceeding limit

{
   "error_message" : "You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API. If 
   you did not set a custom daily request quota, verify your project has an 
   active billing account: http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account",
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"
  }

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Reverse Geocoding</title>
<style>
  /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
   * element that contains the map. */
  #map {
    height: 100%;
  }
  /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
  html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  #floating-panel {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 25%;
    z-index: 5;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
    line-height: 30px;
    padding-left: 10px;
  }
  #floating-panel {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -180px;
    width: 350px;
    z-index: 5;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
  }
  #latlng {
    width: 225px;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="floating-panel">
  <input id="latlng" type="text" value="40.714224,-73.961452">
  <input id="submit" type="button" value="Reverse Geocode">
</div>

<div id="map"></div>


<script>


  function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 8,
      center: {lat: 40.731, lng: -73.997}
    });
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

    document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', 
  function() {
      geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow);
    });
  }



  function geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow) {
    var input = document.getElementById('latlng').value;
    var latlngStr = input.split(',', 2);
    var latlng = {lat: parseFloat(latlngStr[0]), lng: 
   parseFloat(latlngStr[1])};
    geocoder.geocode({'location': latlng}, function(results, status) {
      if (status === 'OK') {
        if (results[0]) 
         {
          map.setZoom(11);
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map
          });


         // infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
         // infowindow.open(map, marker);

       window.alert(results[0].formatted_address);
        } 
      else {
          window.alert('No results found');
        }
      } else {
        window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
      }
      });
     }
    </script>



    <script async defer
   src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XX&callback=initMap">
    </script>


   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Maps: how to get country, state/province/region, city given a lat/long value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013606/google-maps-how-to-get-country-state-province-region-city-given-a-lat-long-va)